# An internal QGIS plugin repository shows available plugin (3.1) version predating the installed version (3.2)

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

The metadata file is updated and the ui and resource files were compiled.  The .xml file is also updated.  Where else does QGIS store the plugin version?  The plugin works just fine but the 'installed version' = 3.2 and the 'Available version' = 3.1.